# android: how to use listview to display search result from 10k entry database

Tags: android, listview

I would like to ask for the idea of implementation.

I have a fixed local database. It contains 10k of string with various length (10 up to 100). I would like to allow user to search a keyword and use listview to display the result? problably bold the text that matched the keyword.

So, I plan to use sqlite. Is that ok? or will be slow for performance? thanks

Comment: SQLite is okay. Anyways what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite will be perfect, specially if you will come up with some sort of complex queries, the important and tricky part here is how to handle such a big amount of information at a time, related to the persistance layer SQLite is the way to go, now in order to show it, there's plenty of different techniques to take, i would recommend you to research about Lazy Load, which is basically load data as user scrolls or updates, the thing is that if one of your results is 1k or more, you could bump with serious memory issues, so take on count using a loading technique in order to maximize your app performance in a friendly way...

Hope this Helps and points you towards the right direction.

Regards!

Comment: thanks, i think i will get more than hundreds of record matched with user query keyword. my concern are speed and stability. Your suggestion is only return 20 records as a time, when user scroll down, fetch the next 20 records and append to it? sounds a smart idea, i will have try! thanks